# snowsql の -q オプションを使用して日本語名のスキーマを SELECT したい

Tags: sql, postgresql

snowsqlのログイン時に-qを使用したクエリオプションを同時実行して日本語名のテーブル名を指定した参照結果を返すようにしたいです。
現状コマンド実施すると、日本語のテーブル名を指定した箇所でSQL compilation errorとなってしまい、snoqsqlにログインできません。このerrorを解消するために方法がありましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。
なお、今回指定したいテーブル名は要件上英名がなく、日本語名しか存在しないです。